# Printing is slow in CUPS as compared to windows for same printer

Tags: printing, cups

I am using Epson-L130 printer with CUPS in raspberrypi for printing files.
I recognized that printing is slow when i run through CUPS however the same document is printed faster through windows.

I have doubt that the process of sending print data to printer in CUPS is slow.

**Update** with info from comment:
1. Windows takes 15 seconds and cups taking 1 Minute.
2. I am using printer's USB for connection. I also tried with Ubuntu with 12 GB RAM but it also performs as Raspberrypi hence i think the problem is with CUPS not with Raspberrypi

Please anyone suggest me with actual problem.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a user of CUPS (as I don't own a printer), but it's my understanding that in many cases parts of it are reverse engineered since manufacturers cannot be bothered to provide linux drivers.  These might then easily underperform, but slow printing is better than no printing... Also, the hardware you are running Windows on is probably much faster.

Comment: I use CUPS to print in several applications with the Pi. What is the difference, 30 seconds verses 2 minutes? Also what is the connection to the printer?

Comment: 1. Windows takes 15 seconds and cups taking 1 Minute.
2. I am using printer's USB for connection.

I also tried with Ubuntu with 12 GB RAM but it also performs as Raspberrypi hence i think the problem is with CUPS not with Raspberrypi

Comment: Please next time edit your question and add additional information there. Don't use comments for that.